# AngularJS bindings with Typescript and ng.IComponentController

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using webpack with Babel and Typescript

I have this controller:

```
// HelloWorldController.ts

class HelloWorldController implements ng.IComponentController {

constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {
}

public over(): void {
    this.$scope.color = this.change();
}
}
```

and his component options

```
export class HelloWorldComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {

public bindings: {[binding: string]: string};
public controller: Function;
public templateUrl: string;

public constructor() {
    this.bindings = {
        color: '=',
        change: "&"
    };
    this.controller = HelloWorldController;
    this.templateUrl = "HelloWorld.html";
    }
}
app.component('helloWorld', new HelloWorldComponent());
```

When I transpile this code I got this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'change' does not exist on type 'HelloWorldController'
```

How I can access the bindings reference inside a controller with Typescript?

Answer (score 2):

You need to **declare** the bound variables on your Controller:

```
// HelloWorldController.ts
class HelloWorldController implements ng.IComponentController {

    change: () => any;
    color: any;

    public over(): void {
        this.color = this.change();
    }
}
```

This way, you tell TypeScript about the existence of these properties on your controller.

Note that during initialization of your component controller, Angular will apply the **bindings** you've set in your component options (`color: '=', change: "&"`) and set your controller's variables to their bound values. This means that you don't have to access these bindings through `$scope` anymore (as done in the over method), which completely elliminates the need to inject $scope into your controller and vastly *increases reusability* of your code.